# Vuejs2 test http request on a form click

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

In my component i have

```
   methods:{
      ContactUs(){
            this.$http.post("/api/contact-us").then((res)=>{
               ///do new stuff
            },(err)=>{
               //do new stuff
            })
        },

    }
```

Now i want to test that the method works

so in my test i have

```
 const wrapper = mount(ContactForm);

it("Contact us method should return a 200 response ", () => {
    wrapper.vm.ContactUs().then((res) => {
        expect(res.data).toEqual(res);
    })
    //await flushPromises();
});
```

But now the test fails and error points to this.$http.post...

How do i test the above function

Comment: You should keep logic like that out of components. Put it in a function or service object and test that.

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

ContactUs needs to return a promise if you want to chain a .then() to it.  this.$http.post already returns a promise, just return its result from ContactUs and your test can chain to it.

```
  ContactUs(){
        return this.$http.post("/api/contact-us").then((res)=>{
           ///do new stuff
        },(err)=>{
           //do new stuff
        })
    },
```